# Defining member variable in header without class definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, global-variables, header-files, member

I've got two files, `list.cpp` and `Header.h`. Segments of the files are below. I know that if the header file is for a class, it is setup different. E.g.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  void foo();
  int bar;
};
```

However, since I'm not really working with a class here (correct me if I'm wrong), am I not able to declare things under `public:` and `private` like below?

Also, if I were to place the global variable `rescan` in the header file as a member variable, below the function definitions, only the `main` function can see the variable. Why is it not within the scope of the other functions?

`list.cpp`:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> results;
bool rescan;

int main() 
{

    vector<vector<string>> list;
    int success = readFile(list);
    vector<vector<string>> bad = findMe(list);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
vector<vector<string>> findMe(vector<vector<string>> find)
{
    rescan = true;
}
```

`Header.h`:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> findMe(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>);
#endif
```

EDIT: I tried this in my header file:

```
public:
    bool rescan;
```

But I got "syntax error: 'public'

Answer (score 0):

If you want your global to be visible in other translation units (TU) (other files), you have to declare them `extern` in those other TUs:

## Header.h:

```
// Include guard omitted 
extern bool rescan; // Declaration
```

## file.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

bool rescan = false; // Definition

// ...
```

## file2.cpp

```
#include "Header.h" // To see extern bool rescan;

void foo()
{
    rescan = true;
}
// ...
```